# Bootstrap 3 with Masonary 3 column format wrapping

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using masonary with Boostrap 3. Instead of 3 columns showing, the 3rd col is wrapping below.

Here is my sample code and a screenshot. Any idea why col-md-3, col-md-5 and col-md-3 are not showing on one line[image]

```
<div id="mason">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 item">

                <!--some content-->

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 item">

                <!--some content-->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 item">

                <!--some content-->

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

  var $container = $('#mason');

  $container.masonry({
      itemSelector        : '.item',
      columnWidth         : '.item',
      transitionDuration  : 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this, might help: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/405

Comment: Hi Dan,
Thanks for replying BUT  I am only loading text content and not images in it and it still seems to warp

Comment: Ok well to debug use inspect element and see what's adding the extra margin/padding.